# How can I check if a file is open by another program in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, testing

In Perl, how do I test if a file of open by another Perl program? I need the first program to be done before the second program can start.

Answer (score 12):

[alt text http://musicritics.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/20061129morbo.gif](http://musicritics.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/20061129morbo.gif)

**FILES DO NOT WORK THAT WAY!**

But seriously, folks, advisory locks with [flock](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) are generally the best you can do. There's no way to *guarantee* that no other program wants to read or write a file at the same time as you.

Comment: Nice post, and it got you the silver perl badge. Congratulations!

Answer (score 5):

You may be able to coordinate the two programs using `flock`:  The first program would lock the file, and the second program would also try to acquire a lock on it, and it would block until the first program releases the lock.

Answer (score 5):

Is [flock()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) available on your system ?  Otherwise, the two programs have be be synchronized, they can communicate thru a pipe or a socket, or via the presence/absence of a file.

Another direction if you are on a Unix-like system, could be use [lsof](http://www.netadmintools.com/html/lsof.man.html) output.

I assume having the first program starting the second one is not feasible.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, [flock](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) works fine on local systems on both Windows and Linux.

You could also, presumably, have the first program [exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) the second program when it's done processing the file.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running on Windows, you could call [`CreateFile`](http://www.google.com/search?btnI=&q=win32+api+createfile) directly with a `dwShareMode` of `0`.

According to [MSDN](http://www.google.com/search?btnI=&q=win32+api+createfile):

> Prevents other processes from opening a file or device if they request delete, read, or write access.

[Win32API::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32API::File) gives access to this call.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically look for whether or not a file is open or in use, if you're on unix there is a wrapper to the `lsof` command to list open files: [`Unix::Lsof`](http://search.cpan.org/~marcb/Unix-Lsof-0.0.9/lib/Unix/Lsof.pm)

Comment: Doing so would be inefficient, and in any case is guaranteed to cause a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Unix, you could also call [fuser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_%28Unix%29).

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the context and my comment may have limited usability in your case, but depending on what you are using the code for/on - Using serial queues to ensure that tasks to execute in a predictable order maybe an option. Your application (written in Perl) will need to explicitly create and manage the serial queues. For more details refer to the following link: [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)